# jQuery v1.6.4 doesn't recognize selectmenu(), Error: "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, select-menu, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I am trying to refresh a 'select menu' with code below using jQuery 1.64 (I need to use this version though it doesn't seem to matter which version I use). When I try to run the selectmenu() function I get the following error.

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (index):22(anonymous function) 
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-git2.js:4402elemData.handle
```

Fiddle:
     http://jsfiddle.net/DNaFv/

html

```
<select id="test">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

$`("#test").selectmenu("refresh");`

Comment: There is no jQuery method called "selectmenu". You're not importing jQueryUI.

Comment: `selectmenu` is not a standard jQuery method. I'm guessing you need to include a plugin library.

Answer (score 1):

[`.selectmenu`](http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/) is part of the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) library. Once you include jQuery UI's dependencies, use `.selectmenu` as follows:

```
$("#test").selectmenu();
```